# How to support rich text for QRadiobutton?

Tags: qt, richtext, qradiobutton

I need to build a new class `MyRadioButton` which is inherited from `QRadioButton` and suport rich text.

Is there any method support directly in the class ? Or do you guys have any idea for this ? Otherwhile I think I'll have to build a new class which is combination of a QRadioButton (for the indicator) and QLabel (for the text) to form `MyRadioButton`.

Comment: You can adapt the code of the [CheckBoxWordWrap](https://github.com/thibDev/qtCustomPlugins) with a QRadioButton.

Comment: @ThibautB.: thank you very much!